# How to edit live theme .info file (localhost)

Tags: theming, .info

I'm currently building a custom theme from the ground up on drupal on localhost.

At the moment I've managed to add my theme and run my custom templates succesfully. However I can't get it to pick up my CSS or JS files.

These were the lines in my .info file

```
stylesheets[all][] = /css/main.css
scripts[] = javascript/javascript.js
```

However I got an error in the console saying:

```
'GET http://localhost/drupal/css/main.css 404 (Not Found)'
```

So I modified the path of the css and js files to something like this:

```
stylesheets[all][] = sites/all/themes/THEMENAME/css/main.css
```

Yet it still can't find it. I'm not sure what's going on. Has the .info file been cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the problem is of `/` present at the starting in your first attempt(`/css/main.css`), try once with:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/main.css
```

**Note:** Clear the cache and check if it works.

Also you can check the following links if it helps:
https://drupal.org/node/171205
https://drupal.org/node/171209

Comment: Yeah, I'd also neglected to take out all the css and js files I'd included in the head of template which was also spitting out a lot of errors!